# How to get touch screen gestures?

Tags: remote-desktop, teamviewer

I have an android tablet that i use to remote control my ubuntu 13.04 netbook, the program i use is team viewer. you ca only control the mouse and it is pretty rubbish like that.

Can i get some touchscreen gestures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since TeamViewer is closed-source, it's up to them to add multitouch gesture support. However, you could probably get some nice gesture features using Easystroke. It uses the mouse to do gestures.

Install it by clicking below:

[image: EasyStroke]

Comment: Will this affect the touchscreen when I remote.

Comment: Can't say for sure. Best way is to just try it out. If it doesn't work, uninstall and *let us know* that it doesn't.